# Slim Autoloading Exception

Tags: php, slim, autoload, psr-4

I am trying to get my slim application to work, but I get this error:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Callable Quiz\Controller\QuizController::index() does not exist in /var/www/html/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php on line 138

> ( ! ) RuntimeException: Callable Quiz\Controller\QuizController::index() does not exist in /var/www/html/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php on line 138

I'm using PHP 8.1 and Slim 4.11

[Project structure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlrXj.png)

My autoload config:

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"Quiz\\": "source/"}
    }
```

Method which should be called:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Quiz\Trivia\Controller;

use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Slim\Http\Response;


final class QuizController
{

    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function index(ServerRequestInterface $request, Response $response, array $args): ResponseInterface
    {
        return $this->container->get('views')->render(
            $response,
            'index.twig'
        );
    }
}
```

I define the route in routes.php as follows:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use Quiz\Trivia\Controller\QuizController;

return [
    'index' => [
        'type' => 'get',
        'path' => '/',
        'class' => QuizController::class . ':index'
    ]
];
```

Later, I add the route in index.php with $app->map(...) to the slim app.

I already tried some solutions from older posts, but nothing worked so far. So I think I'm missing something crucial.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Your `trivia` directory appears to be a sibling to `source`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your autoload config is set to `"Quiz\": "source/` so it expects to find all classes belonging to the `Quiz` namespace in that folder, when in fact the controller you're trying to use is not located there.

You should move the `trivia` folder inside your source directory (with a capital `T` to respect conventions) or update the map to include the trivia namespacing and it's directory.

```
"Quiz\": "source/
"Quiz\\Trivia\": "trivia/"
```

(the double-backslash `\\` is intentional.)